# Not understanding missing return statement

Tags: java

I am new to Java. I am working on a small program practice and getting missing return statement error.

Can anybody help?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class nonstatic1
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // this method works 
        nonstatic2 Ref=new nonstatic2(); 
        int Addition=Ref.add();           
        System.out.println (Addition);     

         String email=email();

    }
       // the one below is the one that does not work and gives me the error
    public static String email()
    {
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Your email Address");
        String email=in.nextLine();

        if(email.endsWith(".sc"))
          return email;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `email()` method supposed to return if it doesn't end with .sc?

Comment: it is suppose to return the email that is being entered by the user

Comment: then remove `if` statement

Comment: The way you entered the code, it will return the email if it ends with .sc. You haven't specified what is supposed to be returned if it doesn't.

Comment: first letter of the class name should be capitalize :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the `IF` statement. You are missing the `else` branch. When the evaluated value of the expression is `false`, your program doesn't return anything, hence the `missing return statement` error.

Change it to something like this:

```
if(email.endsWith(".sc"))
          return email;
else
          return "invalid email";
```

Comment: Hi thank you very much that worked when adding the else.

Comment: also please note that class names should start with an uppercase letter and variables and methods always with a lowercase letter, according to the java coding standards

Answer (score 5):

If `email.endsWith(".sc")` returns false, the function has no return statement.

Since you declared the return type as `String`, the function must always return a String (or null).

So in your case:

```
if (email.endsWith(".sc")) {
    return email;
}
return null; //Will only reach if condition above fails.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(email.endsWith(".sc"))
      return email;
```

Your code here is incomplete. You do have a `return` statement, but only under a single circumstance when many circumstances exist.

```
if(email.endsWith(".sc")) {
      return email;
}
return null;
```

This will work as the logic is now complete and all possibilities are covered.

Answer (score 1):

Your function method

```
public static String email ()
```

is declaring a return value of type `String`. So you must return a value in all cases.

In the function body, you are only calling `return` as a result of an `if`. In the `else` case the `return` statement will not be called. So you need to add another `return` for when the `if` is false.

Answer (score 1):

if you don't want your method to return something in case user enter invalid data than go with this:

```
public static String email()
    {
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Your email Address");
        String email=in.nextLine();

        if(email.endsWith(".sc"))
          return email;
        throw new RuntimeException("Dude, enter normal email man!!!");
    }
```

but any way your method should cover all cases and always come with a return or exception!

Comment: for RuntimeException you don't need throws declaration. please read about checked and unchecked exceptions in java.

Comment: I'll take your word for it, my Java isn't best :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the compiler has detected a code path in your method where you cannot reach a return statement. In particular if `(email.endsWith(".sc")`returns false, then your method would not reach the `return email;`

To solve the proble you can either add at the end of your method `return null;` or `return "";`